# React useEffect hook toggle issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I confused myself on how useEffect works in React. The following code works, but in the opposite way as it is intended. Instead of the background picture appearing after you check the checkbox, it appears when the checkbox isn't checked, and dissapears when it is checked.

```
function Beautifier() {
  const [isBeautiful, setIsBeautiful] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(
    function toggleBackground(shouldShow) {
      document.body.classList.toggle('with-bg', shouldShow);
    }
  );
  
function handleChange() {
  setIsBeautiful(!isBeautiful);
} 

  return (
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" onChange={handleChange} />
      Turn on pretty background
    </label>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render((
  <Beautifier />
), document.querySelector('#root'));
```

I am pretty sure my issue is that I am lacking a return() => in the useEffect hook, but all the things I could think off did not resolve the issue/or broke the function. Not adding CSS, as that part is working fine.

Comment: Don’t toggle the class manually. Re-render the html with the new class

Comment: Is this the correct code? You've declared `toggleBackground` twice and then never invoke it. What is `shouldShow`?

Comment: Yeah, the top toggleBackground staid there as a mistake. Now I got confused in how to call it in the useEffect hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appears you've declared `toggleBackground` twice and don't invoke it. You are also missing a dependency array on the `useEffect`. I'm assuming you meant to actually call `toggleBackground` in the `useEffect` callback. Use the `isBeautiful` state as the dependency, and pass this to the `toggleBackground` function.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  toggleBackground(isBeautiful);
}, [isBeautiful]);
```

You should also use a functional state update to toggle the `isBeautiful` state.

```
function handleChange() {
  setIsBeautiful(isBeautiful => !isBeautiful);
}
```